# Unity Branch.IO Android Deeplinking

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, branch.io

I've recently integrated branch.io with our Unity mobile game. I have been successful on iOS (deep-linking works as excepted) but following this guide (https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Unity-Deferred-Deep-Linking-SDK) I cannot seem to get the same deep link working on Android. I've included the correct plugin files (in the correct directory), I've correctly setup the link scheme on my branch.io dashboard (matches that of the iOS setup) but I can't seem to get it to work.

On device, when I click a test link (which also works on iOS) my Android device (S3) just reports "No Browsers Found", which is also reported if I purposefully break the iOS version, so I assume it's just not registering on Android.

I've included my manifest code, in case you can spot something. I've also tried adding the singletask line to the manifest activity, but still no luck.

Any help would be most appreciated.

```
android:name="com.ingg.werfootball.SplashActivity"

android:label="@string/app_name" >

<intent-filter>

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

</intent-filter>



<!-- Add this intent filter below, and change yourapp to your app name -->

<intent-filter>

    <data android:scheme="werfootball" android:host="open" />

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only error I can find that matches yours exactly is from [GoogleLogin.java](https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/source/browse/trunk/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.login/src/com/google/gdt/eclipse/login/GoogleLogin.java?r=4). I've never experienced a "No Browsers Found" issue before. Do you have a google account associated with the device? Is it functioning properly? Have you tested on more than one device? Do you have Chrome or some browser installed? Please let me know, I'm happy to help.